# Using firstIndex(of: Element) in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have the following code in Swift 4, on Xcode 10

```
        var newCard = deck.randomElement()!

        deck.remove(at: deck.firstIndex(of: newCard)!)
        dealtCards.append(newCard)
```

I'm trying to take a random element from `deck: [SetCard]` and place it into `dealtCards: [SetCard]`

However, Xcode gives me the following error:
[image: Xcode error]

I've been looking through the documentation, but as far as I can tell, `func firstIndex(of element: Element) -> Int?` is a method that exists in `Array`, so I don't understand why Xcode wants me to change 'of' to 'where', when the function has the exact behaviour I want.

What am I missing here?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994720-firstindex: “Available when Element conforms to Equatable.”

Comment: Is your card type Equatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your SetCard type has not been declared Equatable. Thus there is no way to know if a card is present or what its index is, because the notion of a card that “matches” your `newCard` is undefined.

(The compiler error message is not as helpful on this point as it could be. That is a known issue. [Bug reports](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8934) have been filed.)

Comment: That seems to have been the issue. Thanks :)

Comment: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8934  — I’m surprised this isn’t fixed, since the bug is marked resolved.

Comment: Seems to be fixed for Swift 5. With a current snapshot the error message is "Argument type '...' does not conform to expected type 'Equatable'”

Answer (score 3):

The problem has been already explained in the other answers. Just for the sake of completeness: If you choose a random *index* instead of a random element in the array then the problem is avoided and the code simplifies to

```
if let randomIndex = deck.indices.randomElement() {
    let newCard = deck.remove(at: randomIndex)
    dealtCards.append(newCard)
} else {
    // Deck is empty.
}
```

Comment: Good to know - I suppose it also has better efficiency as well since I don't have to search through the array again to find the index of element.

Answer (score 2):

Your `deck` array elements should conform to `Equatable` protocol,

For example as `String` conforms to `Equatable` protocol, the below code snippet works,

```
var arr = ["1", "2", "3"]
let newCard = arr.randomElement()!
arr.remove(at: arr.firstIndex(of: newCard)!)
```